# PHP - Change entire page content on submit button

Tags: php, html

I have two php pages index.php and page2.php.
I want when the first time my website loads it will show index.php which has a search button in it.On clicking the submit button I want to show entire content of page2.php(which now I am showing on page2.php only) on index.php there by removing the need for page2.php.

Comment: *Why* on earth would you want this functionality? Do you just want *page2.php* to show results?

Comment: if(isset($_POST['search'])) include('page2.php');

Comment: You should consider separating your views from your business logic. Using a controller you can render index.php view if no post variables are present and you can render page2.php view if the request is a form post. The URL for the user can be the same (index.php). Read about [MVC in PHP](http://php-html.net/tutorials/model-view-controller-in-php/), but I recommend using a framework like [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/) or [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) if possible.

Comment: see I already have page2.php displaying search results after getting the search term from the input box in index.php.Just need a little recipe to put all that code in a single page

Comment: I need that because page2.php looks kinda incomplete without the search result.

Comment: @user1598243 If the page looks incomplete without search results, I would simply use something like *featured* results in case of an empty search field.

Comment: I guess I have to go with you because my JavaScript code is not working on importing the php file.

Comment: @user1598243, the require import function is PHP, not JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your form so that it reloads the same page:

```
<form method="post">
    // inputs go here
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Then include an if statement that checks to see if the form has already been submitted:

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])){ // form already submitted
    // echo page2.php code here or simply include the code from an external file
}
else {
    // echo the form code above and anything else from the first page here
}
```

Comment: can I call page2.php code like a method so that my page looks bit cleaner and little less complicated.

Comment: you can require/include the code from a different document using the PHP [`require`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) function.  So simply put `require("page2.php");` within the if statement above.  This is the equivalent of copying all code from `page2.php` and pasting it in where you put the `require` method.

Comment: that worked just fine.
Just one more question now how the hell I remove content of the index.php as it is overlapping with page2.php.

Comment: Put the content of index.php in the else block with your form code so it only gets echoed if the form hasn't been submitted.

Comment: Finally its done and all thanks to you man.. within few days I'll be hoping to leave my sucky android job and hosting my own website.     
P.S. How can you vote best answer here ?

Comment: Awesome, glad it worked!  You can upvote helpful answers on the left of the post and click the check mark to select one as the best answer. I appreciate it!  Good luck with your new website. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Copy the script from page2.php and past it in index.php?
And in this closure:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
//
}
?>
```